# Append timestamp while zipping a file

Tags: gzip

I am using the below command to find files which are greater than particular size and `zip` it. How can I modify the below command to include the timestamp at the end of the file?

```
find . -type f -name "*querry_match*" -size +550000000c -exec gzip {} \;
```

Expectation,

```
Before zipping:  querry_match_file1

After zipping:   querry_match_file1.`date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S"`.z
                 querry_match_file1.09-24-2015-02:50:56.z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by timestamp you mean "now", rather than the time of the file, you can try something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "querry_match" -size +550000000c \
 -exec bash -c 'gzip --suffix $(date +".%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S.z") {}' \;
```

where the date command is run separately for each file. If your want 
the same date on all files, as at the start of the find, simply do:

```
find . -type f -name "querry_match" -size +550000000c \
 -exec gzip --suffix $(date +".%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S.z") {} \;
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works fine. Was able to figure out one more alternative

`find . -type f -name "*querry*" -size +55c -exec gzip "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.z" "{}`date +".%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S.z"`" \;`